# Access export to excel doesn't update spreadsheet if referenced by graph

Tags: excel, ms-access, graph, export

I am trying to export to excel from access using the following

```
OutputFileName = DLookup("[DataPath]", "[DataPaths]", "[DataPaths].DataPathID = 1")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "CashflowExport", OutputFileName, True
```

Now in excel that I've added a graph to reference this spreadsheet that gets updated by the above code from a database table CashflowExport, when I export it doesn't update the spreadsheet. How can I get this to update correctly?

Edit: so what doesn't happen is all entries from the database being exported to the specific spreadsheet (which is referenced by a chart) does not update this spreadsheet.

However when I try to update the spreadsheet data (when it has been referenced by a chart it also uses the same four columns) from the database data, it doesn't have the information update in the spreadsheet. So the spreadsheet remains the same with the same data as before and the export from access data doesn't update the data in the spreadsheet.

**Edit2**: The data gets to the spreadsheet CashflowExport from the table CashflowExport by the transferspreadsheet function in vba in access as per the code

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "CashflowExport", OutputFileName, True
```

It is referenced by a combo chart on the spreadsheet called CashflowChart which uses
CashflowExport!$B$2:$B$43 for a bar chart and CashflowExport!$D$2:$D$43 for a line chart

When the chart CashflowChart is referenced to the spreadsheet CashflowExport, the export function TransferSpreadsheet from database table CashflowExport to spreadsheet CashflowExport doesn't update with new data from the database.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does not update? The spreadsheet? The chart? If the chart does not update, look at the data source for the chart. Does it use the correct ranges?

Comment: @teylyn updated hopefully to be more clear.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not update this spreadsheet"? How does the data get into the spreadsheet? From another sheet? By which means? VBA? Formulas? Can you please use the sheet names instead of "the spreadsheet"? Which sheet contains the data import? What is the name of the sheet in your screenshot? What data range does the chart refer to?

Comment: Ok @teylyn I tried to rewrite again. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: So, your question is not really about the chart, but why the data is not updating in the CashflowExport sheet? It reads as if  you think that the chart is CAUSING the data not to update, but that can't be. The chart is just consuming the data that is in the CashflowExport sheet, no?

Comment: When I don't have the chart data referencing the CashflowExport spreadsheet it exports from access correctly which is why I suspect the chart reference being an issue.

Comment: I don't have an explanation for that. From Excel's point of view there is nothing that can be causing this.